# What JSON.decode and JSON.encode do represent?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1420197) the following code:

```
obj = JSON.decode(JSON.encode(o));
```

What does it represent? I see that `JSON.encode` and `JSON.decode` are undefined.

Is this just a pseudocode or `JSON` object is extended adding these functions?

Comment: Looks like that's specific to Mootools 1.2?

Comment: I think this is cloning an object.

Comment: The same question you link explains that it's used to copy an object in Mootools 1.2. Please read it carefully.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I know how to clone objects, but I didn't see that it's related to Monotools.

Comment: the key is, its a de-referenced deep clone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods are specific to the [MooTools library](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON). If you scroll further down you will see the response that should properly work in all browsers without external libraries (the downside being that it will not stringify functions):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
```

The point of the code is to create a deep copy of `o`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I added the link to the methods. Thanks!